# How to change tick labels in d3.svg.axis()

Tags: html, d3.js

I am trying to edit an HTML code of a map. And I want to change the labels of the scalebar by three orders of magnitude less, I mean, if the value is 100000 the scalebar should show 100, without changing the scale domain, just the labels.

###### Actual scalebar

[image: Actual scalebar]

And these are the values i want to appear in the scalebar:

> [0.0, 189.0, 377.0, 566.0, 755.0, 943.0, 1132.0, 1320.0, 1509.0]

I know maybe it's with `.tickFormart` but i don't know which format i have to use. Here is the code:

```
color_map_0caac4580c6c4cdd8684ab303e6dc8e4.x = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([0.0, 1509134.0])
              .range([0, 400]);

    color_map_0caac4580c6c4cdd8684ab303e6dc8e4.legend = L.control({position: 'topright'});
    color_map_0caac4580c6c4cdd8684ab303e6dc8e4.legend.onAdd = function (map) {var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend'); return div};
    color_map_0caac4580c6c4cdd8684ab303e6dc8e4.legend.addTo(map_327a7d6fcd834e0aa3fc248c7a9557c9);

    color_map_0caac4580c6c4cdd8684ab303e6dc8e4.xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(color_map_0caac4580c6c4cdd8684ab303e6dc8e4.x)
        .orient("top")
        .tickSize(1)
        .tickValues([0.0, 188641.75, 377283.5, 565925.25, 754567.0, 943208.75, 1131850.5, 1320492.25, 1509134.0])
        .tickFormat([0.0, 189.0, 377.0, 566.0, 755.0, 943.0, 1132.0, 1320.0, 1509.0]);
```

You can ignore this `color_map_0caac4580c6c4cdd8684ab303e6dc8e4`it's a Folium thing (Python)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your own custom function to `tickFormat`. The input to this function is the tick value and the output is what you want the label to be. In your case, you could do

```
.tickFormat(d => d / 1000)
```